# .NET winforms project deployement on Win 98+

Tags: winforms, deployment, .net-4.0

I have a Winform project built in .NET 4. It contains two forms and one data report (native .NET's report). I want to make an installer for this project that can run on Windows 98 and following versions of Windows. I have tried one click deployment but could not get it working.

I don't know what exactly are dependencies and how to ship them with the project. Would someone can tell me about step by step tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 4.0 is not supported on windows 98.

See the list of supported systems [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7#SystemRequirements).

---

> **Supported Operating Systems:**
>
> Windows 7;Windows 7 Service Pack 1;Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2;Windows Server 2008;Windows Server 2008 R2;Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1;Windows Vista Service Pack 1;Windows XP Service Pack 3
>
> - Windows XP SP3
> - Windows Server 2003 SP2
> - Windows Vista SP1 or later
> - Windows Server 2008 (not supported on Server Core Role)
> - Windows 7
> - Windows Server 2008 R2 (not supported on Server Core Role)
> - Windows 7 SP1
> - Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Comment: @David - .NET 2.0 _can_ apparently be used on windows 98, see http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5&displaylang=en#SystemRequirements

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that - which is why I deleted my answer. It's been a long time since I thought of Windows 98, and answered too quickly from memory, which is pretty iffy at my age.

Comment: @David - to be honest, my first reaction was ".NET on 98? No way...".

Comment: @Oded if i want to have minimum requirement of installing it on XP and all versions that followed, can u guide me through exact procedure. i have not done setup before, so a step by step procedure will be appropriate

Comment: @Muhammad - Just download and run the distributable linked. It is a normal windows install.

Comment: @Oded is there no way i can package it with my project so it checks installation of .net framework as part of installation. my boss wants a single installation package

Comment: @Muhammad - You can include it as a prerequisite in your installer, or package it with the installer (to be run). I don't know the details, but some MSIs can run other MSIs.